# Java Jtable row colour on startup

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, row

doing a library system project with java and I've got the rows to change colour depending on a string however they only change when the string is change and don't detect the right string at startup.

Here is my code for when I click my jMenu item to display books:

```
public void displayBooks() {
    // headers for the table
    String[] columns = new String[] { "ISBN", "Title", "Author", "Publisher", "Pub Date", "Status" };

    Object[][] data = new Object[booksList.size()][6];

    for (int i = 0; i < booksList.size(); i++) {
        Book book = booksList.get(i);
        data[i][0] = book.getIsbn();
        data[i][1] = book.getTitle();
        data[i][2] = book.getAuthor();
        data[i][3] = book.getPublisher();
        data[i][4] = book.getPudDate();
        data[i][5] = book.getStatus();
        System.out.println(book.getStatus());
    }

    table = new JTable(data, columns);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyCellRenderer());
    this.getContentPane().removeAll();

    TableColumn tableStatus = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.addItem("Available");
    comboBox.addItem("Unavailable");
    tableStatus.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

    this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    this.revalidate();

}
```

And now for my cell renderer:

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
    {
        final java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        Object rowValue = table.getValueAt(row, 5);

        Object[][] data = new Object[booksList.size()][6];

        for (int i = 0; i < booksList.size(); i++) {
            Book book = booksList.get(i);
            data[i][0] = book.getIsbn();
            data[i][1] = book.getTitle();
            data[i][2] = book.getAuthor();
            data[i][3] = book.getPublisher();
            data[i][4] = book.getPudDate();
            data[i][5] = book.getStatus();
            System.out.println(book.getStatus());

            if (rowValue == "Unavailable"){
                cellComponent.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.red);;
            }
            else{
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
                cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
            }
            if(isSelected){
                cellComponent.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                cellComponent.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            }
        }


        return cellComponent;

    }
}
```

So to summerise, the rows that have "Unavailable" in the final row do change to red but only when it's changed after the table has been loaded, not on load.

Any ideas. Thanks. :)

Comment: Not very good yet with this but I'll try, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't use "==" for String comparison. Instead you should be using the `String.equals(...)` method:

```
if ("Unavailable".equals( rowValue.toString() )
```

Next, your renderer code is completely wrong. A renderer renders a single cell at a time. So if you have 5 rows of data, the renderer will be called 30 time, since you hove 6 columns of data.

I suggest you search the forum for other examples that extend the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and then modify those examples.

However, one problem with creating a custom renderer, is that you need to create a custom renderer for every type of data in your table. For example a "date" would typically be rendered by a custom date renderer, not a String renderer so the data can be formatted reasonably.

So instead of creating multiple renderers you may want to take a look at [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which provides an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for using your time to answer my question and using equals to fixed my problem. :) and also you're saying that it would be less efficient to use cell render?

Comment: The "==" is not the only problem. As I said, your renderer code is far too complex, There is no need for the "for loop". The looping code is completely wrong. I said that if you have different data types in your table, then you will need to create multiple renderers, one renderer for Strings, one for Integers, one for Dates, one for Booleans etc.

Comment: ahhh, ookey thanks and nope, just using strings for the meantime as it's easier to save to a txt file. I'll figure the better way if I need to but for now, it works. :)